# Cannot login to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I recently upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10. But since the update I cannot connect to the SQL SERVER 2008.

I've already checked:

- The services, they are all running.
- Windows firewall exceptions, 1433 is already added. Also the application added.
- I've ping the server, and it works.
- I've no problem with local connection

**The error message **

[image]

Comment: are you connecting to the default instance or a named instance?

Comment: Use the most recent version of 2008 Server R2, and it's management console. Lower versions are not supported on Windows 10.

Comment: @GarethLyons I am using a named instance

Comment: @PSVSupporter I have no trouble connecting with local user

Comment: is sql server and windows authentication mode enabled?

Comment: If you do a telnet or nmap to the server for port 1433, does it indicate that the port is open?

Comment: @esiprogrammer yes, for both, I use SQL SERVER Authentication

Comment: And what's the error message? If you put the description of the error, we'll be able to help you better than now. @AlfredoMatute

Comment: Did you configure remote server access? Did you enable named pipes?

Comment: Make sure the browser service is running and that TCP/IP and named pipes are both enabled in Configuration manager

Comment: @warwreken the error says: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli every service is running

Comment: SQL worked fine before upgrading to windows 10, after the update i was working on some query, later during the day connections started to fail. I close SQL and restarted the computer. After that no more connections where enabled. I've searched for similar problems and i've found it has something to do with the Windows Defender. I disabled it but nothing changed.